# Responsive Windows Form (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vsto, windows-forms-designer

I have a VSTO Outlook add-in written in VB.net that has Windows Forms. Users with Font/text size scaling set to 100% has no issues in the Windows Form:
[image: Windows Form at 100% font scale]

[image: Font Scale in Windows 10 settings]

However if they change the font scale to something higher than 100%, things get messed up in the Windows form like below:
[image: Windows Form view at 125% font scale]

Do you know how can I make this form responds to font scaling settings and stay readable and viewable?

Comment: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103)  -- Be careful when you have Forms that scale on Font. Test `AutoScaleMode = Dpi` carefully (yes, it may require some layout changes).

Comment: VSTO addin has some issues with windows forms. It will behave differently in every machine regardless of scaling. The best way to overcome this issue is to use WPF instead of Windows Forms. You can refer this:- 
  [WPF in VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782870/looking-for-tutorials-for-using-wpf-in-vsto)

Answer (score 1):

So what I have done so far to fix the issue:

1. Clear the font of the Windows form so that is resets back to the default font name and size
2. Set the ControlBox property of the Windows form to True

[image: font]
[image: controlbox]